# Confused about adding a subview which I set its layer's contents property to a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

For reason of performance,I want to make a cached CGImageRef in static memory space.
So I have a static variable which cached an Image content like following,

```
UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.jpg"];
static CGImageRef imageRef = nil;
if (!imageRef) {
    imageRef = tempImage.CGImage;
}
```

Within UITableView Delegate method,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] .....
    tempImageView.layer.contents = (__bridge id)imageRef;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:tempImageView]; // added this image into UITableViewCell as a SubView.
}
```

This will work at the initial display,
But if I selected a certain cell,the image on that cell will disappear after my selection.(Maybe there are some internal draw operations backing UITableViewCell),I guess that selection event making the cell to a Highlight state for displaying.

How to solve this problem without the following code?I do not want to assign a UIImage to a UIImageView directly.

```
tempImageView.image = tempImageView;
```

Comment: Create static `UIImageView` if you don't want `tempImageView.image = tempImageView;`

Comment: Thanks,it will work fine,But I want to fully understand why it disappear after a selection within above implementation.

Comment: need look at full code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It's possible that yours row was reused with cell where this image wasn't assigned.

Answer (score 0):

After writing some testing code,I had understood the problem happens when the selection event happens on a cell.CGImageRef assigned to a imageview's CALayer property added to the contentView will not disappear after selecting.

That is,when either selected or highlighted passed as a parameter is YES,UITableViewCell will make states of all its subviews to a selected state if they implemented their own behavior.Since UIImageView has several state for highlighting displaying,It will adjust presentation by itself internally.
So If your view simply has only one presentation state you could just set CALayer.contents on a simple UIView,instead of UIImageView.

If I subclass a UITableViewCell and override

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
     //do nothing
}
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
     //do nothing
}
```